# Discrete Laplace: ONB

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Before, consider the discrete Laplace without boundary:
$$\Delta:\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\to\ell^2(\mathbb{N}):(\Delta u)_k:=\frac12(u_{k-1}+u_{k+1})$$

Regard the unitary transformation:
$$U:\mathcal{L}^2(-\pi,\pi)\to\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}):(Uu)_n:=\int_{-\pi}^\pi u(y)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{iny}\mathrm{d}y$$
One obtains the representation as:
$$(U^*\Delta Uu)(x)=\cos(x)u(x)$$

Now, consider the discrete Laplace with boundary:
$$\Delta:\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\to\ell^2(\mathbb{N}):(\Delta u)_k:=\frac12(u_{k-1}+u_{k+1})$$
How to find a representation as multiplication operator here?

Comment: Why do you call it discrete Laplace operator? Why Laplace with boundary and Laplace without boundary are the same?

Comment: The operator $\Delta$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ is not a multiplication operator, but a Toeplitz operator whose symbol is $\cos z$

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk: Hmm ok I don't know to much about toeplitz operator. However it is what *intuitively* I'd understand under discrete laplace. So I did specify the operator just *formally* mentioned above.

Comment: Note, that all "multiplication operators" on $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ should commute with the unilateral shift $(Tu)_k=u_{k+1}$ which corresponds to multiplication operator by $e^{iy}.$ But $\Delta:\ell^2(\mathbb N)\to\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ considered as $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)\to\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ does not.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk: Yes it does not commute with the bilateral shift for  two reasons: Firstly it is defined on a different space and secondly it is not a multiplication operator. That's the point: I try to find a representation as a multiplication operator and that will certainly happen on a different space since it has purely continuous spectrum.

Comment: You can show that $\Delta$ is self-adjoint, with spectrum $\sigma(\Delta)=[-1,1].$ Moreover, the spectrum is simple, hence $\Delta$ is unitarily equivalent to the multiplication operator $f(t)\mapsto tf(t),\ f\in L^2(-1,1).$ Would it answer your question?

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk: Yes that's precisely what I'm looking for. Can you outline the arguments, please?